# Consolidate [youtube-v3-api] and [youtube-api-v3]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

There are two tags for the YouTube API v3:

- [youtube-v3-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-v3-api) (304)
- [youtube-api-v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-api-v3) (244)

These two tags seem to be describing exactly the same thing – I suggest collapsing the former (`v3-api`) into the latter (`api-v3`). Version label at the end seems more common in other tags.

Comment: When it is in the end, it's technically a version *suffix*.

Comment: @HermannDöppes I wonder what happened to Youtube v2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), I've merged both the tags.

That is:

Removed [youtube-v3-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-v3-api) from 305 questions and added [youtube-api-v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-api-v3) to 295 posts.

I've also created a [synonym for that](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/youtube-api-v3/synonyms), in case anyone else creates another tag for the same.

There were no documentation requests and related data and hence there was no headache about that.