# Cleaning up [YouTube-API] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

We have several YouTube tags all pointing to the same API.

The main YouTube API would fall under this: [YouTube data API V3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started). There is only one YouTube API currently, so I am not sure we need to note v3.

- [youtube-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-api)
- [youtube-data-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-data-api)
- [youtube-api-v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-api-v3)
- [youtube-data-api-v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-data-api-v3)

[YouTube analytics and reporting API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/) also falls under the same API, yet we have two tags:

- [youtube-analytics-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-analytics-api)
- [youtube-reporting-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-reporting-api)

**My Proposal:**

Have a single main tag [youtube-data-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-data-api) and the other three should point to that.

Have [youtube-analytics-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-analytics-api) be the new main API and have [youtube-reporting-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-reporting-api) point to it.

I tried to make some of theses changes myself but got [an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eyVf.png):

> Failed to propose synonym:
>   Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators.

Since it's a large clean-up, I figured it may be better to bring it to Meta.

Comment: This seems straightforward, but would be a bit hard. [youtube-api] has 8 times the number of questions as [youtube-data-api], so a synonym won't work here. We will have to merge and rename. The analytics and reporting ones are easy and can be done immediately. Given that the OP is a is a top user in the [google-api] tag, I'd be inclined to do it now, but let us wait for some more time for consensus.

Comment: Oh! and there's also a [youtube-v3-api] synonym which needs to be removed, before we do any of this. If there's no opposing answers, I'll do this tonight when I'm back home...

Comment: I noticed that about youtube-api.  I think that youtube-data-api still makes more sense sorry about giving you guys some extra work.

Comment: While your at it you might want to have a look at [Google-drive-sdk](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-drive-sdk/synonyms)  Main one should be Google-Drive-Api and the others should point to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple parts here. First things, sorting [youtube-data-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-data-api) out. This seems clear cut. The tag wiki, the related tags and everything point to YouTube API V3 - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started. (Note that the OP is also a top user of this tag, and their vote matters a lot)

I've now added the following as synonyms to [youtube-data-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-data-api).

- [youtube-api-v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-api-v3)
- [youtube-data-api-v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-data-api-v3)
- [youtube-v3-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-v3-api), which was earlier added as a synonym here [Consolidate [youtube-v3-api] and [youtube-api-v3]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/342984/4099593).

---

Now coming to [youtube-analytics-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-analytics-api) and [youtube-reporting-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-reporting-api), they were also the same. The fact that the tag wiki of [youtube-reporting-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-reporting-api) was completely plagiarized made it easier to just ignore the tag wiki there. These are now synonymized.

---

Regarding the [youtube-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-api) tag, I am a bit confused.

- [youtube-data-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-data-api) links to https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started, where as [youtube-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-api) links to https://developers.google.com/youtube/, both of which seems different.
- the tag wiki makes it very clear that [youtube-data-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-data-api) is a generalized version of [youtube-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-api).
- The reason that currently only API V3 is present/supported is not a good reason for merging, as when we synonymize these, we will be wrongly tagging the previous questions which were once asked for the V2 of the API.

I still prefer that [youtube-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-api) remain, and [youtube-data-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-data-api) which is being clearly used for V3 also remain separate. However if you feel that they both should still be merged, please do let me know.

---

> Since it's a large clean-up, I figured it may be better to bring it to Meta.

Even if it is a small cleanup it is always better to bring it to Meta. This is because the users who are well versed in the tag might help you decide whether to go forward with the tag cleanups, or not, and also it is easier to find users who can approve the synonym requests, when you post on meta.

Comment: [YouTube-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-api) IMO could be a catch all type of tag kind of like [google-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-api) we already have a number of other youtube api tags  youtube-livestreaming-api
youtube-iframe-api
youtube-javascript-api
android-youtube-api  these are all (Badly named) but probably related to language specific sdks for the api.     I have no objections to you leaving the Youtube-api tag as it is.

Comment: What is your opinion of merging these into the youtube-data-api tag though they seam pretty pointless to me as there is no language specific API for these they are client libraries all pointing to all google-apis **youtube.net-api,
python-youtube-api**

Comment: Looks good to me youtube-data-api as does youtube-analytics-api I follow a lot of these tags and having them under one will make it easer for me.

Comment: @DaImTo Yup, I agree with your first comment ... Leaving it as-is seems the best option IMO too.. If they are badly named, they can all be renamed as well. Remember to open up a new post for that and explain them. Once the community votes, we can rename them. I'm actually not quite sure about merging the client libraries to the tag. It would help the developers of the client libraries to filter based on those tags.

Comment: Cool, if it looks good to you, then I will mark the question as [status-completed]. Thanks.

Comment: they already have tags google-api-dotnet-client  google-api-php-client google-api-nodejs-client the client libraries work for all google apis there is no youtube.net-api  Googles apis are rest based they are not language specific.   I am a contributor on at least three of the client libraries you can trust me :)   Leave it for now i will open new questions for clean up as i have time.   Thank you for your efforts

Comment: No worries, it's my duty :) ... If the client libraries are same, then we can probably add youtube.net-api as a synonym to google.net-api, and so on ... but yeah, feel free to propose the way you feel is correct, that's easier for me too :p